# Usar dados de uma matriz em um Report

Tags: delphi, pascal, fast-reports

Tenho uma matriz como essa que está sendo preenchida em runtime:

```
MatSort[0][0] - Nome1
MatSort[0][1] - InfoNome1
MatSort[1][0] - Nome2
MatSort[1][1] - InfoNome2
```

Porém não sei como referenciar os dados dessa matriz no fast-reports para que seja gerado um relatório com a configuração:

> Nome1 - InfoNome1
>
> Nome2 - InfoNome2

Lembrando que os dados Nome e Info devem estar um ao lado do outro e os nomes separados por uma linha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes injectar esses dados no report . Mas é mais facil e pratico no report trabalhares com datasets.

Porque não preenches um TClientDataSet(Um dataset em memoria que não precisa de estar ligado à BD) com os dados da matriz antes de mandares imprimir o report, e usas o report ligado a esse dataset?

Existem várias formas de o fazer mas sugeria algo como:

1. Colocar TClientDataSet onde tens o fastreport (Form ou Datamodule)
2. Criar os campos Nome; InfoNome no TClientDataSet
3. Fazes algo como (sendo cds o nome do TClientDataSet)

`for i:=0 to limiteMatriz-1 do`
`begin`
`cds.append;`
`cdsNome.value:=MatSort[i][0];`
`cdsNomeInfo.value:=MatSort[i][1];`
`cds.post;`
`end;`

Agora podes ligar o datasource ao report (para isto facilmente encontras documentação)

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta com um exemplo de código para preenchimento desses dados no dataset?

Comment: Editei para te dar um exemplo

Comment: muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda!